# Login Trigger that will accept user input

Tags: oracle, plsql, triggers

We currently have a login `trigger` that traps user information for a session that logs into Oracle from specific Applications (i.e. SQL Plus, SQL Developer).  It takes that information and inserts it into a table for auditing purposes.

Now, if a user logs in via one of these applications we're trapping for, we want to prompt the user to enter information eraltive to why they are logging in and then write it into that same table for auditing purposes.

Any ideas on how we can do this with what we have, or any other ideas on how to accomplish this same thing?

Current `Login Trigger`:

```
begin
   if (dba_monitor.get_program_name = 1)
   then
      insert into dba_monitor.logon_table2
      (username,machine,program, logon_date)
      select username,machine,program,sysdate
        from v$session 
       where username=(select user from dual)
         and username not in ('SYSMAN','DBSNMP');
   else
      insert into dba_monitor.logon_table
      (user_name,logon_date)
      select username,sysdate
        from v$session 
       where username=(select user from dual)
         and username not in ('SYSMAN','DBSNMP');
   end if;
end;
```

`DBA_MONITOR.GET_PROGRAM` Function:

```
    return varchar2
is
   audit_program number :=0;
   audit_select number :=0;
begin
   select 1 
     into audit_program 
     from v$session
    where audsid = sys_context('USERENV','sessionid')
      and (upper(program) in ('SQLPLUS.EXE', 'SQLPLUSW.EXE', 'TOAD.EXE', 'GOLDEN32.EXE', 'MSACCESS.EXE'));
   return(audit_program);
exception
   WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND
   then
      return(audit_select);
end;
```

Answer (score 5):

Not possible - triggers cannot take user input.

You'd be better served having a break-the-glass user account which is locked all the time, and have the user, when checking the break-the-glass user account out, enter their justification at that time.

Oh, and your list of applications is security-by-obscurity; changing the os application name from `sqlplus.exe` to `fluffybunnies.exe` is trivial.